# Div within a Div

Tags: html

I've got this problem, I've placed a div within a div, I've positioned the "title" to be height 50, and then "navbar" below it, so I've put height 100% though the thing is, its not staying within the div, its actually straying away from and out of the div and making a scrollbar appear.

I would love "site" to hog the walls and then all the other div fit in that div.

```
    <div id="site">
        <div id="title">TitleBar</div>
        <div id="navbar">NavBar</div>
        <div id="frame">FrameBar</div>
    </div>
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#site{
position:absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
*border: 1px solid #333;
}
#title{
border: 1px solid #333;
height: 50;
}
#navbar{
border: 1px solid #c38a8a;
width: 200;
height: 100%;
}
```

I've found an image that shows something similar.
http://img176.imageshack.us/img176/4637/picture1zb1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because 100% height actually means "use the same height as the container".

But I didn't quite get all your requirements for this layout, if your navbar is a navigation bar, it should be designed in a way that allows scrollbars to appear when the content is too big.

But I think you're going for the wrong structure to accomplish this, is there any actual reason you want a wrapper div? I've created a fiddle on this, check if this is closer to what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/2/

This other one is yours, in case you wanna play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/yq8PS/3/

Edit: Adding the javascript solution to the answer http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/9

Comment: the header at the top, the nav at the left, the frame in the middle. all within the browser window without a scrollbar appearing.

Comment: Did the scroll appear to you on mine?

Comment: yes, even when I removed the framebar div, it still showed the scrollbar, its because of the header, the narbar is taking the browser window x,y when it should be taking the site div.

Comment: mine is this one http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/2/ my div's classes are top, navbar and bottom, there's no framebar, but if it's still showing, what browser are you using? I've tested this on FF, Chrome, IE9 and IE9 with IE7 doc standards

Comment: I've seen your code and did some changes and noticed that the 100% went well below the browser even when without a scrollbar. http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/4/ I had to set the height to height:84%; to even see it on the page.

Comment: Yes, but what's the matter if it doesn't show the scroll and you can use the background from footer to hide the overflowing sidebar, so the user won't see it?

Comment: from this link I'm wanting nav bar to remain within top bar. http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/5/

Comment: when using position fixed or absolute, 100% width/height is calculated relative from the document instead of the container, my bad not mentioning earlier.

Comment: though this is the problem, right here. http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/8/ navbar is overlapping site when it should be within site like at the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/6/

Comment: how do I get a 100% within the site div?

Comment: gonna give you and uglier, but working solution, use javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/6g6HV/9/

Comment: I did the 3 div using javascript, as I couldn't seem to do it with styles, and connected the javascript function with resize window.

Answer (score 0):

You can make divisions in HTML appear side by side to each other by adding a float property to the css.

```
#navbar{
    border: 1px solid #c38a8a;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Additionally, always add the 'px' unit after a size. Modern browsers assume you mean px, but older ones might not.

There isn't a good way to prevent the overlapping when you have a sidebar that is a set pixel width. To achieve the liquid width (or fluid width) style, you would have to add negative 200px margin on the left to the #frame (to counter sidebar). Then, add another divsion inside the #frame to do the styling for that portion. This is how I have achieved the look on my web site, and it's also the solution used in the previous default Drupal theme (Garland).

```
#frame{
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on overlapping divs? I'm not seeing antyhing like that.

Comment: what are u seeing? cos I'm seeing over lapping, would you post your full code here.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. The problem is that the #frame is over lapping into the #nav-bar correct?

Comment: @karbon It's not visible since there's no border, but the elements are still overlapping.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzNyx/2/ I just added a border and a float:left to the #frame. That really should do it. Looks fine in Safari as well.

Comment: @karbon: but you are seeing a scrollbar. and at 100%, there shouldn't be a scrollbar.

Comment: the thing is then it says 100% it hits the top to the bottom of the browser window, though seeing as there is a header, that as 50px, it then adds 50px so it goes out past the browser making a scrollbar when it really should only reach the site and not bring up a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

IN this context, 100% for the Navbar doesn't mean the remaining height but 100% of the visible heigth of the parent; so if the parent has a height of 400px then Navbar will also have an height of 400px.  If you add to this size the height of the title bar, you get a total value greater than the size of the parent; therefore the appearance of the scolling bar.

While there is usually no problem with the width to make it appears to fill the whole length of a screen, it's very difficult in HTML & CSS to do the same with the height as they have not been designed for this sort of thing; especially with an imbricated structure (div inside div).

Some people will use Javascript to get the size of the screen (browser) and compute the size of their objects accordingly but I don't know if you can do the same with a pure HTML/CSS solution; especially if you want to have your solution compatible accross many browsers.

For more info, take a look at http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/